# Cannot find input file 'libc.lib'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

When I build a project in Release mode, I have the following error:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libc.lib'
```

I've already tried to ignore the .lib file, but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The single-threaded C Runtime (CRT) libraries were removed in Visual C++ 2005.  You'll need to link with one of [the multithreaded libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).  **libcmt.lib** is the multithreaded, statically-linked CRT.